# Why does sbt try to pull my interproject dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt, coursier

I have a multi-project build with a `build.sbt` that looks as follows:

```scala
import lmcoursier.CoursierConfiguration
import lmcoursier.definitions.Authentication

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

val adoMavenUsername = "."
val adoMavenPassword = "ADO_PAT"
val adoRepoIdWithView = "ADO-id"

val adoMavenRepos = Vector(
  MavenRepository(adoRepoIdWithView, s"https://adoMavenHost/adoOrganization/adoProject/_packaging/${adoRepoIdWithView.replace("@", "%40")}/maven/v1")
)

val adoAuthentication =
  Authentication(user = adoMavenUsername, password = adoMavenPassword)
    .withOptional(false)
    .withHttpsOnly(true)
    .withPassOnRedirect(false)

val coursierConfiguration = {
  val initial =
      CoursierConfiguration()
        .withResolvers(adoMavenRepos)
        .withClassifiers(Vector("", "sources"))
        .withHasClassifiers(true)

  adoMavenRepos.foldLeft(initial) {
    case (conf, repo) ⇒
      conf.addRepositoryAuthentication(repo.name, adoAuthentication)
  }
}

lazy val mainSettings = Seq(
  organization := "org.some",
  csrConfiguration := coursierConfiguration,
  updateClassifiers / csrConfiguration := coursierConfiguration
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(mainSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "sbt-test",
  ).aggregate(core, util)

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(mainSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "core",
  ).dependsOn(util)

lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
  .settings(mainSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "util"
  )
```

For some reason, `coursier` attempts to download the `util` package externally during the `core/update` task. This is not what I want, as it should resolve it internally as part of the project. The package is not added to `libraryDependencies`, so I'm baffled why it would attempt the download.
The above example will fail because the Azure DevOps credentials are and Maven repository are incorrect, but it shows the attempt to download `util`.

It seems somehow related to this [Github issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5492).

Comment: This very likely has to do with the custom coursier configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `CoursierConfiguration` constructor sets the `interProjectDependencies` property to an empty `Vector`. To fix this, manually add resolvers on top of `sbt`'s `csrConfiguration` taskKey using `.withResolvers`.

This is what the solution looks like applied to my question, [largely based on this Github comment](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5492#issuecomment-850692474):

```scala
val adoMavenUsername = "."
val adoMavenPassword = "ADO_PAT"
val adoRepoIdWithView = "ADO-id"
val adoMavenHost      = "pkgs.dev.azure.com"

val adoMavenRepos = Vector(
  MavenRepository(adoRepoIdWithView, s"https://$adoMavenHost/adoOrganization/adoProject/_packaging/$adoRepoIdWithView/maven/v1")
)

lazy val mainSettings = Seq(
  organization := "org.some",
  csrConfiguration := {
    val resolvers = csrResolvers.value ++ adoMavenRepos
    val conf = csrConfiguration.value.withResolvers(resolvers.toVector)
    val adoCredentialsOpt = credentials.value.collectFirst { case creds: DirectCredentials if creds.host == adoMavenHost => creds }
    val newConfOpt = adoCredentialsOpt.map { adoCredentials =>
      val auths =
        resolvers
          .collect {
            case repo: MavenRepository if repo.root.startsWith(s"https://$adoMavenHost/") => {
              repo.name ->
                Authentication(adoCredentials.userName, adoCredentials.passwd)
            }
          }
      auths.foldLeft(conf) { case (conf, (repoId, auth)) => conf.addRepositoryAuthentication(repoId, auth) }
    }
    newConfOpt.getOrElse(conf)
},
  updateClassifiers / csrConfiguration := coursierConfiguration
)
```